# Displaying terms as single character unicode symbols in VIM?

Tags: unicode

Does VIM have a way to show symbols as characters?

So `lambda` can be displayed as `λ` (yet keep its underlying ascii text) for example.

Something like emacs [pretty-symbols](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettySymbol)

Comment: Yes, you may want to look at the `conceal` option : `:h conceal`.

Comment: @nobe4 worth adding as answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Vim syntax's `conceal` feature, which allows you to hide matched text or replace it with a single character:

```
:syntax match keyword "\<lambda\>" conceal cchar=λ
:set conceallevel=1
```

For more details, see:

```
:help conceal
:help conceallevel
:help concealcursor
```

Comment: Thanks for the starting point, but this doesn't isolate `lambda`, eg: `lambdafoobar` turns into `λfoobar`

Comment: Probably `syntax keyword` might be better